# Calling methods in a Class and an extended Class, and passing arguments, using an if else

Tags: javascript, class, arguments

I built a class `Add`, and extended it with another class, `TripleAdd`. I have then created a function `gimmeResult`, which should call the methods within the 2 classes, depending on the arguments I pass, based on an `if else`.

The console doesn't display any error. But when I enter gimmeResult(10,20), the Console returns the following:

- `> Add {integer1: 10, integer2: 20}`

Similar behaviour if I write gimmeResult(10,10) in the console:

- `> TripleAdd {integer1: 10, integer2: 10}`

Instead I would like to get a popup showing 200 and 300, depending on the case.

What am I missing? I've been trying to fix this for a while but without succeeding.

```
class Add {
  constructor (integer1, integer2) {
  this.integer1 = integer1;
  this.integer2 = integer2;
  }

  add() {
  return this.integer1 * this.integer2;
  }
}

class TripleAdd extends Add { //constructor and super () will call by default all arguments in the parent class
  tripleAdd() {
  return this.integer1 * this.integer2 * 3;
  }
}

function gimmeResult(integer1, integer2) {
  if (integer1 !== integer2 ) {
      var result = new Add(integer1, integer2);
      return result;
      alert(gimmeResult.add());
    } 
    else {
      var result = new TripleAdd(integer1, integer2);
      return result;
      alert(gimmeResult.tripleAdd());
  }
}
```

Comment: what is weird? you do create an instance of the class and then return that instance, so it prints the instance. You never call those methods inside the alerts because you return before

Comment: A function doesn't continue executing after a `return` statement. The `alert()` calls never happen.

Comment: @quirimmo: I understand the problem is because I write `return result`; but if I delete it or put it after alert(gimmeResult.tripleAdd()), the Console will return an error. What would you suggest to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: and gimmeResult.add() should be result.add()

Comment: @Kurohige comment is why you have an error after removing the `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Add {
  constructor (integer1, integer2) {
  this.integer1 = integer1;
  this.integer2 = integer2;
  }

  add() {
  return this.integer1 * this.integer2;
  }
}

class TripleAdd extends Add { //constructor and super () will call by default all arguments in the parent class
  tripleAdd() {
  return this.integer1 * this.integer2 * 3;
  }
}

function gimmeResult(integer1, integer2) {
  if (integer1 !== integer2 ) {
      var result = new Add(integer1, integer2);
      alert(result.add());
    } 
    else {
      var result = new TripleAdd(integer1, integer2);
   alert(result.tripleAdd());
  }
}

gimmeResult(10,20);
gimmeResult(10,10);
```

Is this something you are looking for? In case of 10,10 the alert shows 300 is case of 10,20 it shows 200.

Comment: Not sure why you wanted to get 600?

Comment: I edited my question for future readers, you are right. Thanks also for the code clarification.